# How to get a value of each element in a row using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

sorry for my English.

I have a row like this:

```
var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
```

And i want to get offsetTop value of each element of it. If i doing just

```
for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    var section = sections[i];
}
```

and then trying to

```
section.offsetTop;
```

it returns offsetTop of the last element.

What should i correctly do to get value of each of it?

Comment: Just reference them by index `sections[4].offsetTop` <- gets the value for the fifth element

Comment: I want to get simple code for all elements together.

Comment: That is simple code for all elements together, anything else would be just more of the same, for instance an array where you do `section[4]` instead

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
var offsets = [];

for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    var section = sections[i];
    offsets.push(section.offsetTop);
}

// offsets has all offsets here
```

Answer (score 0):

Map over all tags.

```
    const sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
    const offsets = sections.map(section => section.offsetTop);
```